# Create New SQL Server Database in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2017. From data connection when I create new SQL Server database, a pop up open and ask for server name. I refreshed but no server name display. What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: If you're looking for a simple dev enviroment database, then localdb may be what you're looking for.  It is a pared back version of SQL Server, and can be installed with VS.  [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42837010/2655263)

Answer (score 5):

I found my answer. From the SQL Server Object Explore, Right Click "Add New Server" Then click to local and select server. After selecting the server i found server name. I [copy the servername from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1LXy.png)

[image]

and paste it to [paste it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQy4V.png)

[image]

"create new sql server database" server name field.. And set database name. Finally it works!

Comment: If you found your answer, don't you think you should accept it?

Comment: not working after following same steps as you answered

Comment: I installed three useless MS programs (as instructed by various MS pages) to try and get this done and all I needed was VS... Glad I finally found your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Install [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server), [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express), or [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb) on your current computer or a computer in your network.

### Explanation

SQL Server Data Tools provides you with a **client** application that you can use to connect to SQL Server instances.

However, it does not include a **server** instance (a [Database Engine Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-instances-sql-server)). In order to have anything populate that list (namely servers), you have to install one of the above options on a machine in your network that you can connect to.

Comment: I don't want to install sql server or sql server Express on my computer. Because visual studio 2017 itself have sql server data tools. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I suspect that localdb is already installed, and that this question is actually about connection strings....

Comment: Maybe. Isn't that an optional part of the Visual Studio installation, though?

Answer (score 1):

you can use localDb... 
create a new connection with the following in your connection string:

**Data Source**=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
**Integrated Security**=True;

then you can create new DB inside visual studio:

[image: Create new DB from Visual Studio]