# Do I need to install microsoft sql server or it comes as by default with visual studio community 2017?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2017

I have installed visual studio community 2017. Now I want to use database inside my  application but i

```html
TITLE: Error
------------------------------

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The system cannot find the file specified

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

i
Can someone tell me what I an doing wrong ?

Comment: Run `services.msc`. Do you have any services running with `SQL` in the name?

Comment: actually i previously installed microsoft sql server 2008 express and then I unistalled it cause when i clicked on start sql service it started and stopped immediately

Comment: I also removed sql server management studio

Comment: sql server agent option is still there and it stops automatically when i lick on start

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install the MSSQL.

MSSQL Server
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

OR

Express Edition
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express

Comment: is it possible to use default database shipped with visual studio community 2017 ?

Answer (score 1):

It does not come by default with Visual Studio. But you get LocalDB out of the box which is a compatible light-weight development version of SQL Server Express and should for the most part serve your needs.
For that you only need to tick certain checkboxes during the installation process, your Visual Studio installation can also be modified later on, see this very helpful post here:

[How to install LocalDB 2016 along with Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774739/how-to-install-localdb-2016-along-with-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Try this: in Visual Studio open Menu `View`, then Select `SQL Server Object Explorer`. If you've done everything right, then there should be a node (probably at the top) that reads `SQL Server`, expand and check if there is a child node called `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`