# Visual Studio cannot open database using .net entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I opend new project in visual studio: .net with Entity Framework and when run the web site and try for example to add new user i get this message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

I haven't installed anything else but Visual Studio such as MSSQL, but I think it's not required as Visual Studio should install these things no?

Comment: Does [SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno) help?

Comment: Did you start VS as admin?

Comment: @stuartd The solution requires to download SQL Server, which I don't have, but should be installed from the Visual Studio, no?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, I started and it didn't help.

Comment: What is your SQL Server connection string?

Comment: Vs doesn't [_always_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774739/how-to-install-localdb-2016-along-with-visual-studio-2017) install Sql Server Express. You could look in "Installed programs" or start the Visual Studio Installer and check what's installed (click "modify")

Comment: Check your local services, is SQL service running ? @OpalKoren

Comment: @stuartd Yes sql server Express installed there.

Comment: @WaleedNaveed I dont have this service there.